# go building error: lzma.h No such file or directory

Tags: go, debian

I'm building [payload-dumper-go](https://github.com/ssut/payload-dumper-go), and I get this error,

```
❯ go build
# github.com/spencercw/go-xz
/home/ecarroll/go/pkg/mod/github.com/spencercw/go-xz@v0.0.0-20181128201811-c82a2123b492/compression.go:36:10: fatal error: lzma.h: No such file or directory
   36 | #include <lzma.h>
      |          ^~~~~~~~
compilation terminated.
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's an easier way for "next time".

[`github.com/ssut/payload-dumper-go`](https://github.com/ssut/payload-dumper-go) uses [Github Actions](https://docs.github.com/en/actions) for building and testing.

Checking its [`.github/workflows/build.yml`](https://github.com/ssut/payload-dumper-go/blob/main/.github/workflows/build.yml) file:

```
...
steps:
  - name: Install dependencies
    run: |
      sudo apt -y update
      sudo apt -y install git golang liblzma-dev
...
```

The last quoted line contains the needed dependencies, namely `git`, `golang` and `liblzma-dev`.

Answer (score 0):

I solve this by brute force trying all `lzma` stuff that Debian had. The actually packaged needed was,

```
sudo apt install liblzma-dev
```

packages that didn't work,

- `lzma-dev`
- `golang-github-kjk-lzma-dev`